# Oozie Shell Action's stdout and stderr output

Tags: oozie

In Oozie site it say 'Shell action's stdout and stderr output are redirected to the Oozie Launcher map-reduce job task STDOUT that runs the shell command'. Can any one tell me where to exactly look at?

Answer (score 4):

Oozie runs the Shell action in a "launcher" *(i.e. dummy Mapper)* YARN countainer (#00002) under control of the mandatory AppMaster container (#00001)

1. check your Oozie logs for "external ID `job_xxxxx_xxxx`"
2. connect to the dreadful YARN console
3. search for `application_xxxxx_xxxx` (yeah, not "job"...)
4. ignore the AM *logs* link, go straight to the *history* link; if you are lucky it will redirect you somewhere
5. hack your way to the *stdout* and *stderr* links

Good luck.

Comment: PS: *stdout* contains a full shitload of useless YARN trace, plus the actual StdOut generated from your shell (with an "Stdoutput " prefix on each line).

Comment: PPS: you may find it easier to retrieve your own output from within the shell itself: just before exiting, get at the files named `$STDERR_LOGFILE_ENV` and `$STDOUT_LOGFILE_ENV`, drop the YARN trace with a bit of `sed`, and ship the Err/Out text to an HDFS file somewhere.