# Hue: oozie parameters

Tags: hive, oozie, hue

I want to pass 2 parameters to my Hiveql script in oozie,
my script:

```
ALTER TABLE default.otarie_appsession 
ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION ( insert_date=${dt},hr=${hr} );
```

My Oozie workflow :

[image]

When i send the job it ask for parameter values, so i put:

[image]

And this is the error:

```
2016-02-05 18:41:55,460 WARN org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveActionExecutor: SERVER[DVS1VM65] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000290-160122145737153-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000290-160122145737153-oozie-oozi-W@hive-a586] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [40000]
```

This is the XML of the workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="hive-a586"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>L&#39;action a échoué, message d&#39;erreur[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="hive-a586">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <job-xml>/user/oozie/some_scripts/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <script>/user/oozie/some_scripts/addpart.hql</script>
              <param>hr=</param>
              <param>dt=</param>
        </hive>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

When i remove all parmeters and use hard coded value, the script works fine, so its clear that i have problem to pass parameters. And my final goal is to pass current date and hour.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting **Hive** parameters with **Oozie** parameters...

```
<param>hr=${bilouteHR}</param>
<param>dt=${bilouteDT}</param>
```

...then setting values for these **Oozie** parameters at submission time?

```
bilouteHR
     00
bilouteDT
     20160105
```

Hope that solves your issue, biloute.

Comment: it gives me this error: `Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [1]`

Comment: Any insight from the YARN logs? cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386470/oozie-shell-actions-stdout-and-stderr-output/33444199#33444199 to find them if you are not familiar with YARN.

Comment: It was lack of permission, it works now ! how can i pass the current date and hour with no hard coded values ?

Comment: Look into EL function `${timestamp()}`